# *ngFor index not getting incremented inside ng-template

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am using Kendo Ui for angular2 and have the following code to display a data grid. I have an ng-template to display checkboxes, clicking on which will give me a incremented integer which I intend to use to implement multiselect in Kendo Ui grid. 
However the let i = index is not incremented inside the ng-template and it always shows the value of i as 0.

The following is my html code-

```
<div *ngIf="model.isTopTen==true" style="height:30px">
    <button style="margin-top: 0.2%;margin-left: 95.6%;border-style: solid;border-radius: 0.2em;" (click)="downloadPdf()">Export</button>
</div>
<kendo-grid [data]="gridView" *ngIf="data && model" [sortable]="{ mode: 'single' }" [scrollable]="'virtual'" [pageSize]="100"
 [rowHeight]="25" [height]="300" [sort]="sort" (sortChange)="sortChange($event)">

    <kendo-grid-column *ngFor="let i = index;let column of model.columnFields;" field="{{column.field}}" title="{{column.title}}">

        <ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-dataItem *ngIf="column.field === 'checkbox'">
            <input (click)="check(i)" type="checkbox" /> {{i}}
        </ng-template>
    </kendo-grid-column>
```

The following is my check function-

```
check(i){
    console.log(i);

  }
```

Clicking on any checkbox always shows 0 for all the checkboxes. However if I use any other property like "column" and pass it in my check function it shows the value to be correct.
What am I missing? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What is the values for `hey{{a}}`?

Comment: I've just printed the value of the increment operator to see its value. It always shows zero.

Comment: Can you please try this: `*ngFor="let column of model.columnFields; let i = index;"` Don't know if the order matters.

Comment: @MaKobi I tried that too. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Why you are using a loop inside the `grid`?  Can you show me your  `model.columnFields` array and `gridview` array?

Comment: @RameshRajendran This is the model.columnFields array-`[{"field":"checkbox"},{"field":"meter_id","title":"Meter ID"},{"field":"rg","title":"State"},{"field":"","title":"District"},{"field":"portion","title":"Portion"},{"field":"mr_date","title":"Read Date"},{"field":"predecimal","title":"Read Value"}]"`

Comment: @RameshRajendran The following is my gridview array- `"{"data":[{"meter_id":"54326881","rg":"IA","portion":"IAQDC07S","mr_date":"2017-02-09","predecimal":"73"},{"meter_id":"54338108","rg":"IA","portion":"IAQDC07S","mr_date":"2017-02-09","predecimal":"125"},{"meter_id":"54338107","rg":"IA","portion":"IAQDC07S","mr_date":"2017-02-09","predecimal":"174"}],"total":3}"`